# Follow up: Find the optimal sequence of stops where the number of stops are fixed

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

I'm trying to code the following problem:

There are n hotels given at a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub> such that 0 < a<sub>0</sub> < a<sub>1</sub> < ... < a<sub>n</sub>. The only places you are allowed to stop are at these hotels, but you can choose which of the hotels you stop at. You must stop at the final hotel (at distance a<sub>n</sub>), which is your destination. Moreover, you are required to complete your journey in exactly d days (i.e have to make d-1 stops in between). If you travel x miles during a day, the cost for that day is x<sup>2</sup>. You want to plan your trip so as to minimize the total cost - that is, the sum, over all travel days, of the daily cost. Find the optimal sequence of hotels at which to stop.

I came up with this dp solution:

Let `dp(i)` be the minimum cost such that the last stop is hotel i.
Base case: `dp(0)=0`.

To compute dp(i), I consider all possible places `0<=k<i`, that we might have stopped before. Thus, the recurrence relation becomes:

```
for i=1;i<=n;i++
  dp(i)=inf
  prev(i)=undefined
  for k=0;k<i;k++
    if (dp(i)>dp(k)+(ai-ak)^2)
      dp(i) = dp(k)+(ai-ak)^2)
      prev(i) = k
```

How do we make sure that this algorithm takes exactly d stops?

Comment: can you add one more dimension to record the number of stop?

Comment: How would the recurrence relation look like then? I'm trying to come up with an efficient solution, maybe of the order O(nd).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this answer on your previous question too but I think you overlooked it. Anyways, let me know if this approach is useful.

Your algorithm would give you the position of stops (int[] k) which would minimize your costs without any consideration of d. I take from your question that you want to convert these k stops to d stops.

There are 3 cases:

1)

> k.length == d;

Problem solved

2)

> k.length < d;

while(k.length!=d) Find the minimal distance(min) between a(n-1) and a(n) for all n. Start traversal from first hotel. Find the first occurrence where a(n) - a(n-1) is min. Now if these two hotels are in your k, find the next occurrence, otherwise break your stop to include this as a separate stop in k and repeat.

If you reach end of hotels, you can do this with the second minimal distance and so on until convergence.

3)

> k.length > d;

while(k.length!=d) This time you need to find minimal distances between two neighbors in k. Merge the two neighbors as one stop, until convergence.

I am not sure if this approach is the optimal one or the right one, but these are my two cents.

Comment: for case 3, when you merge two stops, which stop will stay? in other word, what is the position of the new stop?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic if you have n-2, n-1, n, n+1 stops and you need to merge n-1 and n, compare the following two distances : n-2 to n and n-1 to n+1, if first one is min of the two, merge at n, else merge at n-1
That should work, right?

Comment: Suppose input has 5 stops, at location [0, 4, 5, 7, 10], and output want 3 stops
The algo will merge stops at location [4, 5] first and choose location 4 because (5 - 0) > (7 - 4)
But I think the ans should be stops at location [0, 5, 10], and the algo would not pick location 5